# slow page loading problem SVG Waves Animation

Tags: html, css, web, animation, svg

slow page loading problem SVG Waves Animation

The page loading is very slow while the attached code is in the image, but when I delete the code, the page loading takes only a few seconds to open.

HTML Code

```
            <div>
            <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
                <defs>
                    <path id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
                </defs>
                <g class="parallax">
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

CSS Code For animation

```
 .waves {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10vh;
 margin-bottom: -7px;
 min-height: 100px;
 max-height: 150px;
 }

 .parallax > use {
 animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55, .5, .45, .5) infinite;
  }

 .parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay: -2s;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 }

 .parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: -3s;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 }

 .parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: -4s;
 animation-duration: 13s;
 }

 .parallax > use:nth-child(4) {
 animation-delay: -5s;
 animation-duration: 20s;
 }

 @keyframes move-forever {
 0% {
     transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
 }

 100% {
     transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to answer, but today I had the same problem. In my case deleting the initial `@import...` solved the slowness problem.